# Some <div>s with a for loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I have a for loop and I want to create many `<div>`s with it.
I want to give the `<div>`s am ID from a varible.
Here's the code:

```
var text = $("#cont").text();
count = 1;
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    text += "<div class='ball' id='ball'" + count + "></div><br />";
    count++;
}
```

Comment: I see "I want X" two times in your question, but you forgot to tell us what the question is you have?

Comment: I'm a little confused what your question is. It appears you already have the code to do this. What are you struggling with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've messed up your quotes:

```
text += "<div class='ball' id='ball" + count + "'></div><br />";
```

Your code had the single quote wrong and produced this:

```
<div class='ball' id='ball'5>
```

The number needs to be inside.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit confused what your question is: It looks like you've already got the logic to do what you've specified.

That said, I see a probable error that may be confusing you: You're closing the single-quote on `id='ball'` before you concatenate the count variable. That will result in the div element not having that number as part of its id. Here's a corrected version of the code:

```
var text = $("#cont").text();
count = 1;
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  text += "<div class='ball' id='ball" + count + "'></div><br />";
  count++;
}
```